# Regex Problems with special characters

Tags: php

I keep getting empty results when I try to do filters using regex. I am trying to filter special characters from a httprequest which contains a form input parameter, trouble is, it doesn't post anything I can see,

My code looks like this

```
<?php
$string = 'POST /login.php HTTP/1.1
Host: www.copyscape.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64; rv:53.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/53.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: http://www.copyscape.com/login.php
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 74
Cookie: ck=BXLD2UDMUA88KWGC0GK8WCGOC; PHPSESSID=8cup5f02hbetnbfbbv9vug37q0
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1

login_username=jeezman88%40vfxm.mail.com.com&login_password=(Passw0rd)&log_in=Log+inÿÿÿ7—R';

preg_match('/=\/&\$\%/',$string, $match);
echo $match[1];
?>
```

Now I don't seem to understand why it's not giving any information judging from here
**Edit:** I want to filter and echo this Parameter using `preg_match()` from the text, how I go about it?

```
login_username=jeezman88%40vfxm.mail.com.com&login_password=(Passw0rd)&log_in=Log+inÿÿÿ7—R
```

https://eval.in/789197

Comment: Are you trying to match that entire string till the end?

Comment: @Pavel yes thats what i have been trying to achieve

Comment: check my answer. It works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To match

```
login_username=jeezman88%40vfxm.mail.com.com&login_password=(Passw0rd)&log_in=Log+inÿÿÿ7—R
```

try to [use this regex](https://eval.in/789285):

```
preg_match_all('/login_username=.*$/m',$string, $match);
print_r($match[0]);
```

It matches entire string that starts with `login_username=` till the end of the line. Note, that the regex uses `m`-multiline modifier.

It looks like you are trying to match the entire POST body. You may use [this regex for that](https://eval.in/789292):

```
preg_match_all('/(?:\n\r?){2,}((?:.|\r|\n)*)/',$string, $match);
var_dump($match[1]);
```

Comment: I see it and thanks , but what if its a random web page which doesnt have this login_username as a form parameter, what do i do instead? i havent done regex before

Comment: Thanks Exactly what i needed! Had to change from preg_match_all to preg_match, and with your regex, all is really super!

Answer (score 0):

Wrong index in $match,
check:
https://eval.in/789215

read:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

results are array of matches, [0] - whole regexp match, [>1] - groups matches. Since you have no braces () - results with index >1 are empty.

Comment: Now how do i work on it to echo this login_username=jeezman88%40vfxm.mail.com.com&login_password=(Passw0rd)&log_in=Log+inÿÿÿ7—R

Comment: preg_match_all("/login_username=([^&]*)&login_password=‌([^&]*)&log_in=(.*)?/, $str, $matches);
$unames = $matches[1]; $pwd = $matches[2];

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in /tmp/execpad-aa829283bb74/source-aa829283bb74 on line 17  from here https://eval.in/789248

Comment: yupp, read the docs, and try to fix silly errors)
if you're laizy check: https://eval.in/789275, and happyhacking ;)

Comment: I see it and thanks , but what if its a random web page which doesnt have this login_username as a form parameter, what do i do instead? i havent done regex before

Comment: you can replace login_username with [a-z_]+=.
so regex = /([a-z_]+)=([^&]*)&/
you can test it here: http://regexr.com/3ftig,
however I can't find starting symbol for your example, if you remove "l", it'll work, but first occurance will be a bit ugly)

Answer (score 0):

I think your regular expression is working as expected, but you are accessing `$match` slightly incorrectly. Match looks like this:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "%"
  }
}
```

If your regexp doesn't match, it'll look like this:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(0) {
  }
}
```

It seems like what you are looking for is `array_key_exists(0, $match[0])`

Answer (score 0):

Edit these 2 fields:

```
preg_match_all('/[=\/&\$\%]/',$string, $match);
var_dump($match[0]);
```

https://eval.in/789238

Comment: I want it to Filter this part login_username=jeezman88%40vfxm.mail.com.com&login_password=(Passw0rd)&log_in=Log+inÿÿÿ7—R and echo it.

Comment: then put only that part in the `$string`